# Swift delegation problem without storyboard and segue

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a problem with triggering a method in one Controller from another. I set up all my elements(buttons,views..) programmatically and I'm using a `NavigationController` too.

I want to trigger `fetchUsers()` method whenever a new user logs in or registers so that the tableView reloads its cells with all the users currently populating Firebase.

The problem is that `fetchUsersDelegate?.fetchUsers()` method never gets called because `loginController.fetchUsersDelegate = self` never gets set to self and always stays nil.

So my question is how should i properly set `fetchUsersDelegate`?

**First class**

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {

var fetchUsersDelegate: FetchUsersDelegate?

lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = { 
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegister), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

@objc func handleLoginRegister(){
    if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        handleLogin()
    } else {
        handleRegister()
    }
}

func handleLogin() {

    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
        print("Registration form is not valid")
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        print("Sucessfully logged in")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    self.fetchUsersDelegate?.fetchUsers()

}
```

**Second class**

```
class UsersController: UITableViewController, FetchUsersDelegate{


let cellID = "cellID"
var users = [User]()         
let loginController = LoginController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    loginController.fetchUsersDelegate = self

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() 


}

func fetchUsers(){

    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (DataSnapshot) in

        if let dictionary = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let user = User()
            user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            user.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
            self.users.append(user)

            // if we call just tableView.reloadData the app will crash, insead we need to call it inside
            // DispatchQueue.main.async

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

**Protocol**

```
protocol FetchUsersDelegate {
    func  fetchUsers()
}
```

*Edit:

This is how i set up my rootViewController in the AppDelegate class

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UsersController())

    return true
}
```

And this is how i present the LoginController, the handleLogout() method is inside the UsersController if that helps.

```
@objc func handleLogout(){

    do{
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch let logoutError{
        print(logoutError)
    }

    let loginController = LoginController()
    present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: It’s hard to say how to trigger method in one controller from another without knowing the relationship between the two controllers. If one presented the other, then you can pass reference to one to another. If they’re possibly not directly related (i.e. one is not presenting the other, but happens much later), then you can use `NotificationCenter`. It’s hard to say which is best without knowing the relationship between the two view controllers, if any.

Comment: Edited the post, i hope it gives an idea about the relationship between the two controllers. I don't really know what kind of relations there are between controllers since I'm relatively new to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
let loginController = LoginController()
```

is the problem it has no relation to the presented vc and it's a new separate instance , so when you present the user

```
let user  = UsersController()
self.fetchUsersDelegate = user
present// add child// user
```

if the user can login at same time the users table exists in screen , then i expect it's a menu list or a child vc